# Filter Controls in FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, search, user-controls, flowlayout

I have a FlowLayoutPanel that I fill with a custom `UserControl`, and I have a `TextBox` at the top of the form that I would like to use to filter the results. Each `UserControl` stores it's properties, but I wasn't sure how to filter using those properties.

For example, say my `UserControl` contains something like this:

```
// snip..
public string Text { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
//snip..
```

How would I then go about taking the entry from the `TextBox` and comparing it against both `[usercontrol].Text` and `[usercontrol].Description`? It has to be searched inside the text, not just from the beginning.

Once I've filtered the appropriate results, I would like those to be the only ones visible. Do I have to flush them all and rebuild it with only the applicable ones, or can I just remove the ones that don't match the filter?

I know this may be a very noob question, I just don't know where to start with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through all of the user controls on the `TextBoxChanged` event and if it does not match your criteria, set the visibility to collapsed. It would look something like this:

```
private textBoxTextChanged(obj sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(UserControl uc in flowLayoutPanel.Children)
    {
        if(!uc.Text.Contains(textBox.Text) && !uc.Description.Contains(textBox.Text))
        {
            uc.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            //Set Visible if it DOES match
            uc.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good news: It works. Bad news: When iterating through almost 500 objects, it locks up for about a half minute. Is there any faster way of doing this? Or, perhaps, some messed up way of doing it in a `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: Edit- I don't think it's iterating through so many objects that slows it down, I think it's actually changing the `Visibility` that's affecting it. Is there any way to make this smoother?

Comment: Right, that is an issue. Are you actually displaying all 500 objects at once? or would it make sense to limit the amount displayed?

Comment: Try this using a search delegate in a separate thread.  This will free up the GUI and will offload the heavy work onto the delegate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the